# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form' not found

Tags: zend-framework

I've started using Zend framework, and Im following this simple Zend form tutorial. The form is located in application/forms directory I have included the Zend framework in the Path (by going to computer properties). However when i access form.php page, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form' not found
```

I have also tried by copying the Zend folder from the Zend framework in the library folder of the application, however error still remains same. Thanks.

Comment: What 'this' tutorial? There is no link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing two notions: the system path and the include path.

The system path is an operating system concept. When you ask the OS to execute a command, the system path is a list of places to look for the executable.

In contrast, the include path is a PHP concept that tells PHP a list of folders in which to look for files invoked by PHP `include/require` statements.

Any path that you find in "Computer > Properties" is almost certainly the OS-level system path. What you need to do is to make sure the Zend folder on the PHP include path, either by moving the Zend folder or by modifying PHP's include path to include a point to the Zend folder.

In a typical ZF app, the include folder is set in `index.php` (the front controller). So, the only explanation for not finding Zend_Form is that the autoloader is not being instantiated.

If you are using `Zend_Application`, this happens automatically. However, it seems like you are bypassing `public/index.php` and the whole `Zend_Application` instantiation by trying to directly "access" a file called `form.php` directly. If this file contains only the definition of your form (extending `Zend_Form`), then the absence of autoloading could easily explain the error message you are getting.

I'd try instantiating the form in a controller action, by which time in the request processing cycle, the autoloading is probably already in place.

[At that point, given the file locations you cite, we might run into a resource-loader issue, but that's a somewhat different issue that can be handled by instantiating a `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` in your `Bootstrap`.]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not use `Zend_Loader`. You should focus on it.

You can also manually in your custom form class include `Zend_Form` class.